# R to separate rows for multiple columns linking ordered values

Tags: r

Is there a way to use separate_rows from tidyverse or equivalent over multiple columns where the values between columns will be matched based on the order they appeared?  E.g. convert

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1:3), 
       b=c("name1, name2, name3", "name4", "name5, name6"),
       c=c("match1, match2, match3", "match4", "match5, match6"))
```

into

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | match1 |
| 2 | name2 | match2 |
| 3 | name3 | match3 |
| 4 | name4 | match4 |
| 5 | name5 | match5 |
| 6 | name6 | match6 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We may use `separate_rows` on multiple columns if they have the same number of string separators

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   separate_rows(b, c)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
      a b     c     
  <int> <chr> <chr> 
1     1 name1 match1
2     1 name2 match2
3     1 name3 match3
4     2 name4 match4
5     3 name5 match5
6     3 name6 match6
```